When an object is thrown towards the sky it starts to gain potential energy, why?
I didn't think so because when an object is thrown towards the sky it already has kinetic energy and it looses it's energy due to the gravitational force of the earth.
When the object looses all of it's kinetic energy and it's motion becomes zero then the Earth pulls it toward it and due to this the object again have only the kinetic energy. Throughout the whole experiment the object doesn't possess any potential energy.
There are two types of force:

Push force
Pull force

The push force makes the object move towards the sky and the pull force of gravity makes the object come down towards the Earth's surface.

The object has kinetic energy when it leaves your hand. But then, it has no kinetic energy at the top of its arc. And finally, it has kinetic energy again when it approaches the surface. You've heard of conservation of energy, right? So, where did the energy go when the object was rising? Where did the energy come back from when the object fell back down?

What is the question? What are Newton’s laws?

The object has energy, whether it is kinetic or potential. There is a point in its trajectory where the object is not moving, and this is at the highest point of its trajectory. At this point, it has zero kinetic energy, but where did the energy go?
The answer is that it is now in a position with higher gravitational potential. The force of gravity was always acting on it, and this is what brought it to a stop at the peak of its trajectory. Now, there's nothing in gravity's way. Gravity is going to accelerate the object back down to earth. How much is gravity capable of doing? Does the object come flying down at an arbitrary velocity?
The answer is that (ignoring air resistance) the object can only return to its original position with the same amount of energy it started with. You can measure this energy by observing how high the object goes against the force of gravity vs the amount of energy you give it; therefore, an amount of non-kinetic energy depends on this height. We call that energy potential energy, and the object has all it can ever have at the peak of its motion. So, from the second you let go of the object, it begins to slow down and thus gain potential energy (based on the object's position), which is then poured back into the kinetic energy (based on the object's velocity) of the object on its way back to the earth.

There are two ways to view the exchange of kinetic energy and potential energy.  But before I do, I'd like to point out that your learning of physics will be much much easier if you drop the concept of "push forces" and "pull forces."  There are simply forces.  Push and pull are not important distinctions and will only get in your way.  Revisit the difference between push and pull in a year or two when you're ready to talk about the stability of motion (pulling something tends to be stable, while pushing tends to be unstable).  Until then, there's just forces.  There's a force applied to cause the ball to go up, and there's a force of gravity pulling it down, nothing more.
In both of these views, energy is not lost to gravity.  The energy is converted from kinetic energy to potential energy.  If it were lost, then it would be hard to explain how the ball could be moving fast when it gets back down to the altitude it was thrown from.  If it lost all of the energy, how'd it "find" the energy on the way down?  The answer is simply that it isn't "lost;" it's "converted to potential energy."
So, two ways to think about this.  The first way is probably most in line with how you are being taught right now.  In this view, gravity is a field.  We know the graivity is caused by the Earth, but from the problem's perspective, all that matters is that there is a field applying a force on the ball downward.  Well, that's almost all that matters.  The other thing that matters is that this is a conservative field. What does that mean?  A whole lot, and you'll learn about them as your courses continue.  But one of the key attributes of a conservative field (or a "conservative force, if people prefer that term) is that it is path invariant.  It doesn't matter if you throw a ball up to 5m, or you lift it with your hands to 5m, or you catapault it around the moon, and it comes back to 5m above the ground.  In all of those cases, the force of gravity will provide the exact same energy to the ball as it falls from that 5m point.
Don't believe me?  Try it.  Science was built not on teachers telling us how the world works, but on experimenters trying things and seeing if they fit patterns.  Testing things is part of the game!  Take two balls.  Lift one straight up to eye level, and take one on whatever convoluted path you feel like, such that it ends up at eye level.  Drop them at the same time, and they'll fall at the same rate.
At some point, your teacher will tell you that the equation for this potential energy due to gravity is $PE(h)=mgh$ where $m$ is the mass of the object, $g$ is the gravitational constant for the field, and $h$ is the height of the object (with respect to some arbitrary point, like ground level).  And you can choose to believe them, or you can drop objects from a bunch of heights and measure their speed when they hit the ground to build up an empirical mapping.  Science!
What Newton found was that energy was not created nor destroyed.  It was merely transformed.  Kinetic energy can be transformed into potential energy, and potential energy can be transformed into kinetic energy.  The Work-Energy theorem captures this concept, and you'll eventually learn it.  So as the ball goes upward against the force of gravity, its kinetic energy decreases.  At the same time, its moving upward, so its potential energy ($PE=mgh$) is increasing... and they decrease and increase at the same rates.  If kinetic energy of the ball goes down by 1 Joule, then potential energy of the ball goes up by 1 Joule.
Why is this so, you ask?  We don't know.  Science doesn't try to answer "why" in that sense.  It strives to predict what is going to happen.  Newton did a bunch of experiments, built predictive models, and noticed that some functions had this strange property we now call "conservative."  Later scientists found more conservative forces, and nowdays we believe that all forces can be explained via conservative forces (4 of them, actually).  Why?  Ask the philosophers.  Me?  I'm going to predict the trajectory of some balls thrown in the air!
(Okay, that's a lie.  The philosophy side is a lot of fun too.  But that's a different stack exchange, and a different answer!)
I mentioned there's two ways to think about this.  In the above approach, gravity was just a conservative force caused by "something," and the potential energy is associated with the ball.  For entry level physics, this is the usual way of thinking about it.  However, sometimes it helps to think about it a little different.  Consider the moon and the Earth.  Does the moon have potential energy because it's at a high altitude above the earth, or does the earth have potential energy because it's at a high altitude above the moon?  Do they both have potential energy?  Sometimes you'll start asking questions like that, second guessing what objects have potential energy.  At that time, it's useful to switch to another way of thinking.
In this way of thinking, objects have kinetic energy (because they have a velocity), but potential energy is associated with the system, not any one object.  In this way of thinking, it's not that the moon has $7.68\cdot10^28\text J$ of potential energy, or that the Earth has $7.68\cdot10^28\text J$ of potential energy, its that the Earth/Moon system has $7.68\cdot10^28\text J$ of gravitational potential energy due to the distance between those two bodies.  That potential energy can transform into kinetic energy by speeding up the earth, or transform into kinetic energy by speeding up the moon -- that potential energy simply isn't owned by any one object.
Both approaches are functionally equivalent.  They take different approaches, but predict the exact same motion.  So we use whichever one is most convenient for a problem.  Likely, in the early days of your physics career, you'll only need to use the former.  Later, you may find that you're puzzling over which object should have potential energy, or whether you're double-counting the energy.  At that time, remember that there's the second approach.  For instance, as shown above, the second approach (where potential energy is an attribute of the system) is the easiest way to think about a lot of celestial mechanics.  On the other hand, if you're looking at the potential energy of a stretched rubber band, the first approach (where potential energy is assigned to an object), makes life much easiser!

Means according to you if I threw a ball toward the sky and think there is no gravity and air pressure is present then the ball will move down wards because it have a kinetic energy and it will covert into potential energy

You have told that science doesn't try to answer why but a normal person will not think that why it is happening but a person who have interest in science he will think that why it is happening

@PriyankaBahadur please read the work-energy  link I put in the answer.  You will not be able to generalize an understanding of kinetic and potential energy to different situations without it.  Once you understand it, reconsider your example with no gravity and let me know if you still think the ball must move dowward according to what I say

As for science not answering why,and people wanting to know why, that is a reasonable critique of science.  Science predicts.  It does not answer why.  The closest to "why" that it gets is to predict more and more general situations, like expanding from a situation with gravity to one without (which calls for understanding work and energy).  Eventually you get as generic as science has gotten, and the "why" becomes "we observed it"

(and if you don't wish to follow w the link to the work energy theorem, the reality is that without a conservative force, like gravity, the potential is zero.  The potential field is defined by the force)

I think what you're missing is that potential energy can be negative. If you hold a ball and drop it from infinity, at the start the ball has no kinetic and no potential energy. When you drop it the ball gains kinetic energy. I think what you're asking is where does this kinetic energy comes from. It comes from potential energy droping below zero. So when it gains 1J of kinetic energy it has -1J of potential energy. The total is always zero as energy is conserved.

Every body has total energy, which is the sum of its kinetic and potential energy .This total energy is always conserved for conservative forces.
 $ U=V+K$
 Here U denotes total energy, V denotes potential energy and K denotes kinetic energy.
 $K=\frac{(mv^2)}{2}$
When a body is thrown up, it initially has high kinetic energy . As it moves up, it starts to slow down due to gravity and thus loses kinetic energy, which is converted into potential energy. So potential energy increases with height.
Gravitational potential energy is given by 
 $V=mgh$ which again indicates the relation between height and potential energy.
When the body reaches maximum height where velocity is zero, it falls down again, the reverse happens and the body again gains kinetic energy.


The push force makes the object move towards the sky and the pull
force of gravity makes the object come down towards the Earth's
surface.

You are mistaken about this part. If you throw an object upwards its vertical velocity is entirely due to the energy you imparted to it with your hand and not due to any push force of gravity.
From the moment the object leaves your hand the gravity is continuously pulling downward on the object on the way and on the way back down. The object is continuously decelerating from an initial positive velocity, down to zero at the apogee and then from zero to a negative velocity as it falls back down. Because the kinetic energy is a function of velocity squared the kinetic energy is the same at the end as it was at the start. The kinetic energy lost as it climbed is stored as potential energy and is is returned as it falls back down.
Potential energy has many forms. It can be stored as tension in a spring or as chemical energy in a battery and in these forms the potential energy is iv visible and measurable, but the potential energy in the gravitational case is difficult to see and so it understandable that it can appear to be intangible.
